# ScadaBR or Mango(a scada software)

Tags: scada

Mango is a scada software.And now I want to develop its graphic views and have a breakthrough  in it.I am really confused what to do next. So could somebody gives me ideas? I will be appreciated..

Thank you for any help provided! 
Best regards

Answer (score 3):

ScadaBR is a branch from Mango M2M when it was formerly an Open Source Project. Since version 1.12 Mango has changed its license.

Both SCADAs are great, fully functional with lots of protocols and easy to modify (forum and documentation available). But **ScadaBR will always be an OS project**. It has a SOAP API and recently a REST API. ScadaBR is a Brazilian project and does not yet has a English translation for its website or wiki. Only a forum for english speakers. I suggest the use of Chrome with auto translate, it should do the trick =]

**Mango M2M**

http://mango.serotoninsoftware.com/forum

**ScadaBR**

http://www.scadabr.org.br

Regards

Comment: Now with wiki in english thanks to blackfox - https://sourceforge.net/p/scadabr/wiki/Home/

Comment: Now, based on ScadaBR it created project Scada-LTS.